# spring AOP JDKdynamicAopProxy InvocationHandler

Tags: spring, proxy, aop

How to see what interface implementation InvocationHandler Spring creates / generates then creates a proxy object?

proxy object has a constructor, which is called with this implementation

```
public Proxy(InvocationHandler paramInvocationHandler)  {

   super(paramInvocationHandler);

}
```

Comment: debug allows see the code?

Comment: Do you have a maven project?

Comment: yes, i'm use netbeans

Answer (score 1):

JDKdynamicAopProxy is implementation of the InvocationHandler.
this is normal method to create proxy object.

```
public Object getProxy(ClassLoader classLoader) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is " + this.advised.getTargetSource());
    }
    Class[] proxiedInterfaces = AopProxyUtils.completeProxiedInterfaces(this.advised);
    findDefinedEqualsAndHashCodeMethods(proxiedInterfaces);
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, proxiedInterfaces, this);
}
```

just call Proxy 's method with args with  the classLoader,interfaces,InvocationHandler.